# Multidimensional Array For Grid Based Movement

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, unity-game-engine

I am practicing my programming skill using Unity3D. I have a grid set up that has coordinates in an x,y type of setup.

```
[0,0] to [10,10]
```

With all the numbers in between (I.E. 5,5 would be close to center of the map).

The thing that I am trying to do now is figure out a mathematical formula to calculate the coordinates my character can move. If the character is at position 5,5 and has a movement radius of 2 what is the most efficient way to return a list or an array of coordinates my character can move to? Every single grid square is its own object and have public variables for its X and Y so once I have the available results actually using them in the code isn't hard.

Here's what I'm trying so far (I'm ignoring the out of range possibility for right now, that's an easy fix):

```
for(int x = currentGridSquare.xCoord - myMovementRange; 
x <= currentGridSquare.xCoord + myMovementRange; x++){
for(int y = currentGridSquare.yCoord - myMovementRange;
    y <= currentGridSquare + myMovementRange; y++)
{
    //Starting at 5,5 with a movement range of 2 should
    //start this process at the value of 3,3 which
    // is incorrect
}
}
```

I may be too tired to actually calculate a formula for this but I've been searching and haven't come across anything so if anyone's had experience with this and knows a quick way to do it I would be greatly appreciative.

Update: The values that I am expecting this to return would be coordinates. In this example starting at 5,5, the values I'd want back would be [3,5],[4,4],[4,5],[4,6],[3,5],[4,5],[5,5],[6,5],[4,6],[5,6],[6,6] and [5,7]

Comment: Is it all integers? Ie, no sqrt(2) mess?

Comment: Yah everything is an int

Comment: So could you update the question with the expected output for the given case?

Comment: Updated and thinking further on this if there is a way to calculate the cost to move to the squares I guess I could iterate through every grid square on the map and add the grid square to a list if it meets the cost requirement.

Comment: Well at first glance i figured you could test the abs(x1-x2) + abs(y1-y2) <= move range.  but that would be inefficient to extrapolate to a larger set.

Comment: Does that make sense?

Comment: Yah I'm going to try to implement that formula. My biggest grid won't be much bigger than this one so if this formula works it'll be perfect.

Comment: Sweet. Shouldnt be hard to iterate over, check formula, and add to result list.

Comment: Yah I appreciate the insight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I used formula Ben provided and came up with:

```
foreach(var gridSquare in allGridSquares)
{
   if( (Mathf.Abs(myX - gridSquare.Xcoord) + (Mathf.Abs(myY - gridSquare.Ycoor) >= myMovementValue)
   {
        gridSquare.activate();
   }

}
```

I know that if the grid starts getting bigger than the distance formula will be more complicated and I will update this later if that's the case but for the size of my grid this works wonderfully.